# PATCH request behaves like GET in MERN CRUD app

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, axios, request

In a MERN CRUD app with JWT authentication I am trying to use `PATCH` request to edit the `text` field in my MongoDB documents. But it behaves weirdly.

Another `PATCH` request that changes the `status` boolean field works perfectly fine. It makes a request with a `todoId`, an empty object and Auth header.

However, in the Network tab I can see that the request for `text` which is practically the same but with different URL (`'/edit'` added) and a non-empty object behaves like a `GET` request to `http://localhost:3000/api/todos/` with `304 OK` status for some reason. But in Postman it works as intended.

It is supposed to be, for example, `http://localhost:3000/api/todos/62bae4bdda66c364463c58d0/edit`. A working patch request to `status` is to: `http://localhost:3000/api/todos/62bae4bdda66c364463c58d0`

The issue is probably syntax, so please take a look at the code for both patch requests, in each file top is for `status` (working), then for `text` (not working):

**Frontend:**

Dispatching in *TodoCard.js* from *TodoSlice.js* (`editedTodo` is a String, so `{editedTodo}` is an object with editedTodo key)

```
// status
  const handleStatusUpdate = () => {
    dispatch(updateStatus(todo._id))
  }

// text
  const handleEdit = () => {
    dispatch(editTodo(todo._id, {editedTodo}))
  }
```

In async functions in try-catch blocks in *TodoSlice.js*:

```
  // status
  return await todoService.updateStatus(id, token)

  // text
  return await todoService.editTodo(id, editedTodo, token)
```

Axios requests in *TodoService.js*:

```
// status
  const response = await axios.patch(API_URL + todoId, {}, config)

// text
  const response = await axios.patch(API_URL + todoId + '/edit', editedTodo, config)
```

Finally, **Backend**, routes in *todoRoutes.js* (`protect` is auth middleware):

```
// status
router.patch('/:id', protect, updateStatus)

// text
router.patch('/:id/edit', protect, editTodo)
```

And *todoController.js*

```
// status
  const updatedTodo = await Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { status: !todo.status }, { new: true })

// text
const editedTodo = await Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, { text: req.body.editedTodo }, { new: true })
```

One is working, other is not. Again, the issue is probably syntax. I would really appreciate any help since I've been stuck on this for some time. Thank you in advance!